# Force webpage to invalidate properties?

Tags: javascript

I have a page with an elements that can get removed from it, sometimes the rest of the elements readjust after its removed which is good. Sometimes though they do not, is there a way to force them to readjust or invalidate?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post some pertinent code. HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Comment: Care to elaborate/post an example?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking how to force the browser to "re-position"/"re-draw" all elements on the page after some of them have been removed from the DOM.

If I correctly understood your question, I vaguely remember dealing with that problem before. I'm pretty sure I set the `display:` attribute of the body tag to `block`:

`document.body.style.display = 'block';`

If that doesn't work, you could try something upsettingly hackish, like this:

```
document.body.style.display = '';
document.body.style.display = 'block'
```

Regardless of which one works, I'd definitely wrap the code in a well-named `function` to make it clear what you're trying to do!